# Is there a way to convert all NAs in certain dataframe column only if two separate conditions are met in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements, na

any help with this R problem would be appreciated beyond belief!! Apologies in advance for i) not using correct syntax/formatting. ii) this has probably been asked in other ways i can't find. iii) I'm finding it really hard to describe in words (or using simplified expressions) what I'm trying to achieve...

In a nutshell, converting NAs to 0s is really straightforward, however, converting NAs in a specific dataframe column under two or more "if" conditions is a different story.

My dataframe is a log of how many times analysts have been late with their report type in the past year (all made up):

```
LateReporters

   Analyst Name  Report Type     Secured-Late  Unsecured-Late
1  Nick          Unsecured       NA             NA
2  John          Unsecured       NA             3
3  Emily         Secured         4              NA
4  Karen         Secured         NA             NA
5  Leslie        Unsec&Sec       NA             4
6  Joanna        Unsec&Sec       2              NA
7  Scott         Unsec&Sec       NA             NA
8  Stuart        Unsec&Sec       1              3
```

This is what i am trying to achieve:

```
LateReporters

   Analyst Name  Report Type     Secured-Late  Unsecured-Late
1  Nick          Unsecured       NA             0
2  John          Unsecured       NA             3
3  Emily         Secured         4              NA
4  Karen         Secured         0              NA
5  Leslie        Unsec&Sec       0              4
6  Joanna        Unsec&Sec       2              0
7  Scott         Unsec&Sec       0              0
8  Stuart        Unsec&Sec       1              3
```

Rules:

1) If analyst reports "Unsecured" 'Report Type' only, then any NAs in the 'Unsecured-Late' column should be changed to a 0 as they have genuinely never been late - and any NAs in 'Secured-Late' column should remain as NA (as they don't report it).

1) If analyst reports "Secured" 'Report Type' only, then any NAs in the 'Secured-Late' column should be changed to a 0 as they have genuinely never been late - and any NAs in 'Unsecured-Late' column should remain as NA (as they don't report it).

3) If analyst reports "Unsec&Sec" 'Report Type', then any NAs in the 'Unsecured-Late' and the 'Secure-Late' column should be changed to 0 as they have genuinely never been late.

Attempted Code (and many many many others):

```
LateReporters <- if (LateReporters$'Report Type' == "Unsecured" & LateReporters$'Unsecured-Late == is.na(LateReporters$Unsecured-Late)) { LateReporter$Unsecured-Late [which(is.na(LateReporters$Unsecured-Late))] <- 0
}

LateReporters <- if (LateReporters$'Report Type' == "Secured" & LateReporters$'Secured-Late == is.na(LateReporters$Secured-Late)) { LateReporter$Secured-Late [which(is.na(LateReporters$Secured-Late))] <- 0
}

LateReporters <- if (LateReporters$'Report Type' == "Unsec&Sec" & LateReporters$'Unsecured-Late == is.na(LateReporters$secured) | LateReporters$'Secured-Late == is.na(LateReporters$secured) ) { LateReporter$Unsecured-Late [which(is.na(LateReporters$Unsecured-Late))] & LateReporter$Secured-Late [which(is.na(LateReporters$Secured-Late))] <- 0
}
```

Any suggestions where I'm going wrong would be great.

Many thanks

Comment: vectorized conditionals require `ifelse` (or `dplyr::if_else` or `data.table::fifelse`), then should not be attempted with `if`/`else`. `if` requires length 1, `&` suggests the possibility of length other than 1. You should not use `&` within `if`, it is appropriate however in `ifelse` and friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, a little clunky-looking:

```r
LateReports <- within(LateReports, {
  Unsecured_Late[is.na(Unsecured_Late) & Report_Type == "Unsecured"] <- 0
  Secured_Late[ is.na(Secured_Late) & Report_Type == "Secured"] <- 0
  Unsecured_Late[is.na(Unsecured_Late) & Report_Type == "Unsec&Sec"] <- 0
  Secured_Late[ is.na(Secured_Late) & Report_Type == "Unsec&Sec"] <- 0  
})
LateReports
#   Analyst_Name Report_Type Secured_Late Unsecured_Late
# 1         Nick   Unsecured           NA              0
# 2         John   Unsecured           NA              3
# 3        Emily     Secured            4             NA
# 4        Karen     Secured            0             NA
# 5       Leslie   Unsec&Sec            0              4
# 6       Joanna   Unsec&Sec            2              0
# 7        Scott   Unsec&Sec            0              0
# 8       Stuart   Unsec&Sec            1              3
```

Comment: r2evans thank you so much for the super fast response, this worked perfectly in one hit!... This has been so helpful!!! Thanks again. I was not seeing this approach anywhere, but i now have many uses for it.

Comment: As some advice, it is feasible that if you start getting into grouping operations (apply a function to multiple rows for just one single analyst, for instance), then the base R functions work great but are a bit more obscure. For beginners, I think `dplyr` is a great package to use for grouped calculations/analysis, and @Greg's answer is a step in that direction with its use of `case_when` (which is similar to nested `ifelse`, a function I mentioned in an original comment). No need to jump head-first yet, but keep it in mind if you find yourself thinking "per analyst" multi-row conditionals.

Comment: I will take the advice certainly. Maybe an initially shallower but broader knowledge of R/functions, explored with dplyr, is the way to go. Amazed to see how efficiently concise your solution was (and @Greg).  Yes well, conceptually speaking, what I've been trying to achieve with functions, conditionals and the layers of data I have are much less daunting now. This has really helped, much appreciated and @Greg

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr::case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(`Secured-Late` = case_when(`Report Type` == "Secured" & is.na(`Secured-Late`) ~ 0,
                                    `Report Type` == "Unsec&Sec" & is.na(`Secured-Late`) ~ 0,
                                    TRUE ~ `Secured-Late`),
         `Unsecured-Late` = case_when(`Report Type` == "Unsecured" & is.na(`Unsecured-Late`) ~ 0,
                                      `Report Type` == "Unsec&Sec" & is.na(`Unsecured-Late`) ~ 0,
                                      TRUE ~ `Unsecured-Late`))
# A tibble: 8 x 5
     X1 Analyst_Name `Report Type` `Secured-Late` `Unsecured-Late`
  <dbl> <chr>        <chr>                  <dbl>            <dbl>
1     1 Nick         Unsecured                 NA                0
2     2 John         Unsecured                 NA                3
3     3 Emily        Secured                    4               NA
4     4 Karen        Secured                    0               NA
5     5 Leslie       Unsec&Sec                  0                4
6     6 Joanna       Unsec&Sec                  2                0
7     7 Scott        Unsec&Sec                  0                0
8     8 Stuart       Unsec&Sec                  1                3
```

Comment: This worked too! Thanks for detailing this so quickly. Interesting to see how case_when can be used to tackle this type of work. Again, had not seen this explained in other sources?! I have more uses in mind for this too now. Thanks again!!!